# how to create dedent function in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a code editor and I want to create dedent function when editor some indented line
I create indented function but I am unable to create dedent function

I have created dedent function but it's not working correctly

Please help
Whenever I press backspace button is draw rectangle on text widget:

this :-

[image]

this is dedent function I have created:

```
def backspace(event):
        widget = event.widget
        line = widget.get("insert linestart", "insert lineend")
        match = re.match(r'^(\s+)', line)
        current_indent = len(match.group(0)) if match else 0
        if current_indent == 4*(len(match.group(0))):
            new_indent = current_indent - 4
            widget.insert("insert", event.char + " "*new_indent)
        else:
            new_indent = current_indent - 1
            widget.insert("insert", event.char + " "*new_indent)
```

this is my full code(not full code short version of real one):

```
from tkinter import*
import re
def autoindent(event):
        widget = event.widget
        index = widget.index(INSERT)
        index2 = "%s-%sc"%(index,1)
        word = widget.get(index2,index)
        line = widget.get("insert linestart", "insert lineend")

        match = re.match(r'^(\s+)', line)

        if word == ":":
            current_indent = len(match.group(0)) if match else 0
            
            
            new_indent = current_indent + 4
            
            widget.insert("insert", event.char + "\n" + " "*new_indent)
        else:
            whitespace = match.group(0) if match else ""

        
            widget.insert("insert", f"\n{whitespace}")


        return "break"
def backspace(event):
        widget = event.widget
        line = widget.get("insert linestart", "insert lineend")
        match = re.match(r'^(\s+)', line)
        current_indent = len(match.group(0)) if match else 0
        if current_indent == 4*(len(match.group(0))):
            new_indent = current_indent - 4
            widget.insert("insert", event.char + " "*new_indent)
        else:
            new_indent = current_indent - 1
            widget.insert("insert", event.char + " "*new_indent)
root = Tk()

editor = Text(root)
editor.pack()

editor.bind("<Return>",autoindent)
editor.bind("<BackSpace>",backspace)



root.mainloop()
```

this is what I have created:
[image]

Comment: _" I am unable to create dedent function"_ - why are you unable? What's preventing you from doing it?

Comment: I have created one but Whenever I tried to run my terminal show error

Comment: Please show us the error.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you haven't defined font or tabs in your editor.

Try this.

```
from tkinter import font

root = tk.Tk()

TAB = 4
textfont = font.Font(family = "Consolas", size = 10)
indent = TAB * textfont.measure("M")

editor = tk.Text(
    root,
    font = textfont,
    tabs = indent)
editor.pack()
```

This approach obviates the need for a backspace function.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I want to backspace function for indented function for example when user type ":"  and then press enter line indent function indent line but if user want to dedent that indented then he press backspace button and dedent the line I want to create function like this and

Comment: Sir please help me to create this dedent function